# How to add java class folders instead of jar's in linux shell script

Tags: java, linux

Below is my existing script.

```
 for f in $( find $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/lib/ -name "*.jar" ); do
  CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:$f"
 done
```

The above one is working fine until the java classes wrapped with .jar. But now there is now more jars, and all java classes maintained in the readable folders(means packages).

So I want to add my all java class folders to the class path. Any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Ashok

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you are asking for this.

If the path of the folders are same you can use `-or` with `find`

`find $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/lib/ -name "*.jar" -or -type d`

`-type d` will also find directories

Answer (score 0):

In Java 6 and higher, one can add all jar-files in a specific directory to the classpath using wildcard notation.

When folders appear in the classpath with a wild card suffix, all executable files in them (eg `.jar`, `.class`, etc) are automatically included.

Change your script to concatenate `foldername/*` instead of *files*.

Comment: Huh? IMHO an classpath entry may refer to some .jar, or an folder containing .class files; but since when are .jar's in folder entries recognised?

Comment: @GyroGearless sorry wasn't quite complete. It works if you add wildcard, eg `path1/*;path2/*`

Comment: @Bohemian can you please provide some example?